# Make a deployable Java EE project from a java project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, build, glassfish

I have coded a small Java EE project that consists only of EJBs, helper classes and their tests.
The project is a maven project and creates a jar.
Right now, all tests are happening with JUnit and JMockit.
Now I want to deploy my application to a local glassfish 4.

What do I have to do, to deploy the project? I know that normaly a root Project with a root-Pom is created, that holds a EAR Project with the ear-Pom and the EJB Project with the ejb-jar.
I checked out the jee-simple-archetype, which was - for my kind of project - much to sophisticated and not simple at all. Could somebody explain how I package and deploy my app correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that normaly a root Project with a root-Pom is created, that holds a EAR Project with the ear-Pom and the EJB Project with the ejb-jar

This is not necessarily the "normal" way. You can deploy a .jar containing EJBs on its own. Typically you would do this if the EJB beans are either called remotely (via RMI/@Remote or via SOAP/@WebService) or if the application contains some job-like logic (@Singleton/@Startup, or maybe JSR 352 Batching).

> Could somebody explain how I package and deploy my app correctly?

In your pom.xml you should use `<packaging>ejb</packaging>`, that's basically it (assuming you have an otherwise valid pom.xml). The resulting jar can be deployed on its own. For GlassFish you would use the [asadmin deploy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2433/deploy-1.html#SJSASEEREFMANdeploy-1) command for this.